# Do I have to fill foreign key values?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

Do I have to fill the field of a foreign key in MySQL or any other database manager?.

I'm writing the data of a table and when I get to the field that is a FK from another table, I have to write something, is this necessary?

I understand that the value in that FK is stored inside the parent table where it comes from.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a value unless the foreign key column is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the is actually a foreign key constraint in place (available in InnoDB only). In some cases frameworks, applications, or database management tools create "false" foreign keys that exist only in the application and not actually in the database.  Also, the limits on how you can insert/update/delete data realted to the foreign keys can differ based on the type on constraint in place.

Here is the MYSQL documentation for definitive information:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Specifically, look at the "Referential Actions" section for comments on the behavior between the tables.